# Typo3: Show last created Pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm currently working on a page that is supposed to show the 4-5 last added Pages of a specified section:

```
Category 1
 - page1
 - page2
     -page2.1
     -page2.2
 - page3
 - page4
 - page5
 - page6
Category 2
 - more pages
Category 3
 - page1
```

So the Idea is that I want to show the pages 2-6 of category 1 (page1 is older than 2-6) with all subpages on page 1 of category 3. I know that there is a content element of Typo3 that provides the 5 last edited/ updated pages. Is there a way to do the same but with the last 5 created pages?
(Typo3 8.7)

Edit: I mainly want to show the link to the Page.

Comment: It should be possible to extend `tt_content.menu_subpages` (MenuSubpages.typoscript) with `alternativeSortingField` and `maxItems`.

Comment: I managed to build a sitemap only for the pages I want. I am able to sort the pages by crdate but only inside of the first subpages. I have to sort them across all subpages.